# Getting values inside <td> tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

Variable HTML tags :

```
<td class="center line"><strong>Banana</strong></td>
<td class="center line red"><strong>(Apple)</strong></td>
<td class="center">Orange</td>
<td class="center red">Cherry</td>
```

this does not work.

```
<td class=\"center[ line]?[ red]?\">[<strong>]?[(]?[A-Za-z]*[)]?[</strong>]?</td>
```

line, red, strong Tag is constant.

Help !

Comment: Use `( line)?`, `( red)?` etc.

Comment: Rather, use a XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match all the above four lines,

```
<td\s*class=\"center(?: line(?: red)?| red)?\">(?:<strong>)?\(?[A-Za-z0-9]*\)?(?:<\/strong>)?<\/td>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX1qT8/1)

Use non-capturing groups or capturing groups instead of `[ line]?` to make the `<space>line` as optional one. It would be `( line)?` or `(?: line)?`.